# Extending the admin panel in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have several objects with some functions that I would like to be able to run via the admin panel. So far, I've not found a way to add them as actions to the admin interface.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you intend to perform these actions on a selection of items ?  If so, have you seen the [django admin actions docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) ?  I use them to perform custom actions quite swimmingly.